# issue with DHTMLX2.5 calendar

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX 2.5 calendar. I am attaching calendar to an input field.

```
<script src="../dhtmlx_suite/js/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dhtmlx_suite/skins/dhtmlxcalendar_dhx_skyblue.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dhtmlx_suite/css/dhtmlxcalendar.css" />
<script src="../dhtmlx_suite/js/dhtmlxcalendar.js"></script>
<script>
var myCalendar;
function doOnLoad() {
    myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject(["calendar"]);

}

</script>

    <div style="position:relative;height:280px;">
        <input type="text" id="calendar">   
    </div>
<script>
doOnLoad();
</script>
```

When I enter some invalid date e.g 'xyz' in the input field, and click the input field, it replaces the value with string 'NaN-NaN-NaN'. How could avoid this? and keep the user eneted value as it is in the textfield. So when there is an invalid date in the input field I expect calendar popup to ignore that and just open the current month.

Comment: You can attach event to the calendar. For example something like onMonthChanged() and return FALSE. But to make it works the way you want you should have a boolean variable that becomes TRUE when the user focus the input field and inside the event you attached to the calendar check if the the variable is TRUE or FALSE. if it is TRUE then return FALSE inside the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validator function which checks whether the content of your input is syntactically correct. If it is not correct, you can put back the old value to the input and prevent other actions.